# Are there water heating elements that literally explode when turned on dry?

Tags: safety, cooling, heater

When I grew up these things were pretty commonplace:

[image: Water heater spiral]

In case you've never seen one, it's a very primitive water heater that you simply place inside a pot of water (or a jar, or even a cup of tea-to-be).

Today they're almost extinct, for obvious reasons (yet I can still find some being sold new), but 30 years ago I remember my grandma cautioning me that if "I ever ran this without putting it in water, it would overheat and explode".

Now clearly - turning it on and just leaving it on the table is a bad idea in and of itself - but would it literally *explode*? I suspect that something like that would not pass today's safety standards, so maybe there was something like that in The Olden Days™?

Could this have been a real warning, or was it just an old wive's tale to scare off the little kid from simply burning the house down?

P.S. To address the "off-topic" closing - this isn't a question about how to use this. This is a question about whether such a *type* of heating elements *exists* (or used to exist) that would be designed to run exclusively in water (which provides cooling) and would literally explode when allowed to overheat. This *is* a design question, just using this particular device as an example (the only example known to me).

Comment: It doesn't have to explode to burn the house down. Nowadays it would probably have a thermal cutout to switch it off if it went too far over 100 degrees, which would only happen if it operated outside water.

Comment: Reopened - as while not originally posited as a design or development question (but is now) it is instructive in safety, design limits and applications. Spehro notes what it would take to create a survivable in-air version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Heating elements don't usually explode, they are made out of metal, metal usually melts at high temperatures. (unless there was something inside the coil which is unlikely)

What the warning was most likely attached to was: "don't plug in the element, then put it in the water". If you do that, then the water does "explode" because the element is more than 100C and water would instantly boil when you drop the heating element in water. Operation in water may have also been part of proper operation of the heater (to keep it cool enough not to melt the heater) and part of the operating instructions.

Instant boiling does not happen if you plug in the element while it's in water because as long as there is water around the coil, it will keep the temperature to below 100C (the energy will go into boiling the water and stay at ~100C until the water is gone). So as long as you have water around the heater, it won't melt.

Comment: Btw - did you close my question? I've added an edit. :) Although since there are already two excellent answers, I don't really mind.

Comment: Also, yes, it might have been that the warning was about placing it inside the water when hot. That was a long time ago and my memory isn't very clear on that.

Comment: @vilx 5 community members voted to close. I agree with your reasoning and voted to reopen. If enough people vote to reopen or a mod believes its valid then it will be reopen.... but that's unlikely in this community.

Comment: @Passerby - I understand, it's OK. I realized when I was posting that this was a slippery topic. And, re-reading just now, I realize that I did a poor job originally of explaining that I was interested in _types_ of heating elements.

Answer (score 4):

You could make something like that to survive operation outside the water but it would require an expensive swaged heater, and would get dangerously (red) hot outside of liquid.

In fact those things are an aluminum tube with a fiberglass sleeve inside and inside the sleeve is some nichrome wire. That's it. They're depending on the cooling from the liquid to protect the heater.

If you operate such an "immersion heater" outside of the liquid, the heater will get hot enough to melt and die. It might melt its way through the fiberglass and contact the aluminum causing a shock hazard. It won't likely cause a fire hazard. It won't "explode".
Most electric hot water heating elements are made much better, but they generally won't survive running dry for many seconds either.

Source: I dismantled one of those things (working, before and after) ca. 1967. I believe they had them with a cigarette lighter plug (12V) for car use as well. Heat your coffee. Ugh.

Comment: Well, it could be made survivable with a thermal feedback of some sort, too. But it would then be much more complex and less reliable.

Comment: For example you could use a different metal as a heating element, one with more of a temperature coefficient than nichrome. Maybe stainless steel. Measure voltage and current to calculate resistance. If the resistance gets above some threshold, then that means the element is too hot and needs to shut down (for, say, 1 minute or more). Just a sketch of an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I bought one of these in China for use to heat an otherwise too cold hotel bath for evening soaks. I destroyed it when I left due to it's danger if not used with great care.

That was maybe 12 years ago but I'd expect they are still for sale there.

They have their place - but not for baths except in "expert hands" :-).

Used uncooled "Explosion" would probably be too extreme an expectation, but very-hot, loud and spark spewing demise could be expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed true. It has happened to me 2 years ago . It exploded forcefully  and inside the metal spiral was the heating element and sand. I  was playing with the heating element without anything to absorb the heat. I have an explanation for this though.  All this part has to be watertight and airtight in order not any liquid to have actual contact with the heating resistor and live electricity. Unfortunately this builds a high pressure inside if is not cooled down by the liquid. It made terrible noise, and i was very lucky that i did not got hit by shrapnel, as i was not expecting that. The reason i answer here, is because I found another heating element, and i was curious if anybody experienced this situation before.

Comment: Well, now, this is interesting! :) Seems like there's conflicting information out there. Do you plan on a controlled destruction of the other heating element, possibly with video documentation? :)